# Making a calibration matrix

Tags: matrices

I have two spectrophotometers. The first spectrophotometer is a professional color measurement instrument that has been calibrated in factory. It has a physical resolution of about 8nm and it communicates the spectral data sampled with 3.333333 nm steps, i.e, for each measurement I get 106 reflectance values between 380 and 730 nm. The second spectrophotometer is a miniature sensor that has 8 overlapping channels across roughly the same visible range, 380 to 730 nm. It is uncalibrated and I only know the peak sensitivity of each channel:

```
410 440 470 510 550 583 620 670 nm
```

Finally, I have a set of measurements made under the same conditions with both machines.

I would like to use this data to calibrate the response of my low-resolution instrument. I have read somewhere that it is possible to use `non-negative-least-squares` in order to create a calibration matrix with which I will be able to get a better response from my instrument.

First thing I did is to resample the data from my low resolution instrument in the same format as my high-resolution instrument using linear interpolation. Now I have two sets of data containing each 25 spectral measurement. Each spectral measurement has 106 values:

```
High_res_data  = ((val_1_1, val_1_2, ..., val_1_106), ..., (val_25_1, val_25_2, ..., val_25_106))
Resampled_data = ((res_1_1, res_1_2, ..., res_1_106), ..., (res_25_1, res_25_2, ..., res_25_106))
```

Being unfamiliar with matrix calculations, I'd like to know how to proceed to obtain a calibration matrix that I can apply to any new resampled data from my low-resolution instrument. Another question concerns the use of linear interpolation for resampling: is it a good approach or would it be better to use another type of interpolation?

Comment: Which object do you expect to be non negative? Why use non negative least squares?

Comment: @user619894 well I guess it doesnt make sense to have negative values because the signal of a spectrophotometer is either null (noise only) or positive